# VB.NET Excel file not connecting with virtual datagridview

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I am trying to write a module in my VB.NET application, but it isn't working properly.
I am trying to create a datagridview, and load an excel file into it. However, the Excel isn't loading in it.

Code below

```
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Net.Mail

Module m_IslsHpPtSplit
Dim UploadFilePath As String
Dim UploadFileName As String

Dim dgv1 As DataGridView
Dim dgv2 As DataGridView

Public Sub LoadFile()
    dgv1 = New DataGridView
    dgv2 = New DataGridView
    Try
        Dim filedialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        Dim path As String
        filedialog.Title = "Select file"
        filedialog.InitialDirectory = "Desktop"
        filedialog.RestoreDirectory = True
        If filedialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            path = filedialog.FileName
        Else
            path = Nothing
        End If
        UploadFilePath = filedialog.FileName
        UploadFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filedialog.FileName)
        Dim dtSheet1 As New DataTable

        If Not path = Nothing Then
            Using cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
                Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With _
                    { _
                        .DataSource = path, _
                        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" _
                    }
                Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0; IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;")
                cn.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString

                cn.Open()

                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [FNAC$]"
                    Dim dr As System.Data.IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                    dtSheet1.Load(dr)
                    dgv1.DataSource = dtSheet1
                End Using
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show(dgv1.RowCount)
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    SplitFile()
End Sub 'LoadFile
```

After that, I need to perform some calculations etc, but the line

```
MessageBox.Show(dgv1.RowCount)
```

actually returns 0. The excel file has 316 lines in it.
How can I get the data to stick to the new dgv?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stems from not actually adding the dgv1 to any control collection (the datasource is attached but in actually no rows have been created to display). If you were to `MessageBox.Show(dtSheet1.Rows.Count)` you would probably notice a count proving that the data is being read in. Playing around, I added `Form1.Controls.Add(dgv1)` immediately before your `Messagebox.Show(dgv1.RowCount)` and produced received a proper count.